# Determinant of order 4 question

Tags: matrices, determinant

I don't get this, maybe you can explain me how you solve it

"Write down all the terms appearing in the determinant of order 4 which have a minus sign and contain the factor a23"

Thanks a lot

Comment: Consider the determinant $$\begin{vmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}&a_{14}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}&a_{24}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}&a_{34}\\a_{41}&a_{42}&a_{43}&a_{44}\end{vmatrix}$$ ; if you expand it out, you should see terms that fit the criteria in your question...

Comment: What is your definition of "determinant"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One definition of the determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix is:

$$\det(A) = \sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)a_{1\sigma(1)}a_{2\sigma(2)}\cdots a_{n\sigma(n)},$$
where $\sigma$ runs over all permutations of $S_n$.

You are being asked to write down all those in which $\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)=-1$, and $\sigma(2)=3$.

For example, the same question with a $3\times 3$ determinant: the permutations that have $\sigma(2)=3$ are $\sigma=(2,3)$ and $\sigma=(1,2,3)$. The first one is odd, the second one is even, so the only term with negative sign would be
$$\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)a_{1\sigma(1)}a_{2\sigma(2)}a_{3\sigma(3)} = -a_{11}a_{23}a_{32}.$$

If your definition of determinant is by using minors/cofactors, then consider expanding along the second row (or the third column), so that the only terms that contain the factor $a_{23}$ are those in which you compute the minor of $a_{23}$. Keep track of the sign and do the $3\times 3$ determinant of the minor to figure out which terms satisfy the desired conditions.

Again, using a $3\times 3$ example,
$$A = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} &a_{12} &a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} &a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{array}\right),$$
expanding along the third column, the only terms with a factor of $a_{23}$ are the ones that come from
$$-a_{23}\left|\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11}&a_{12}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}
\end{array}\right|  = -a_{23}\Bigl( a_{11}a_{32} - a_{12}a_{31}\Bigr).$$
So the only one with a negative sign is $-a_{11}a_{23}a_{32}$, same answer as above.

Comment: I realise this post is years old but I am struggling to understand the solution using permutations. What does the notation $\sigma = (1,2,3)$ mean exactly? You say that it is even and that the other is odd, however I can’t see where the inversions are that give you $sgn(\sigma)=-1$?

Comment: @benmcgloin: it is cycle notation; $(1,2,3)$ means $1\mapsto 2$, $2\mapsto 3$, $3\mapsto 1$; any number not listed is sent to itself. I don't know you are calculating inversions; it is an even permutation because it is equal to the product of an even number of transpositions.